# how to save data in UTF-8 in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a `<textarea>` element in my `<form>` which is supposed to save arabic text into a mysql database.

I have set the charset of my page as `<meta charset='UTF-8'>` I have also set the `accept-charset = "UTF-8"` in my `<form>` tag. And I have set the `collation` of the column in my database to `utf8_unicode_ci`

But whenever I submit the form, my database is saving the arabic text like so:`Ø¨ÙØ³Ù’Ù…Ù Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‘`

Instead of saving it like so: `كيف حالكم`

I am using php as my backend. Can anyone guide me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql)

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored